# Using select tag for a string attribute without set values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to use a select tag to populate a model attribute. I have something like this:

**The model:**

```
class MyModel
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :my_attribute
end
```

**The controller:**

```
class MyModelsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @my_model = MyModel.new
  end
end
```

**The view:**

```
= form_for @my_model do |f|
  = f.label :my_attribute
  = f.select :my_attribute
```

I don't have a collection of set values for `my_attribute`, and I want to populate the select tag for `my_attribute` from another website using AJAX on the fly.

But currently I am getting an `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass` error when I visit `/my_models/new`.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: *> But currently I am getting an undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass error when I visit /my_models/new.* Maybe this error doesn't relate to select tag? Why do you think it relates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass an empty array in `f.select`

```
f.select(:my_attribute, [])
```